# Passing in functions

Tags: c#

I want to overload a function without using optional parameters. When I use generics, I run into a problem; however, it works with simple types. I am confused so thanks for the help. Class B uses int to validate my syntax; while class C is what I want to accomplish.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;


namespace X
{
    class A
    {
    }
    class B
    {

        public static int f(int i1, int i2)
        {
            return i1 + 12;
        }
        public int ix(Func<int,int,int> f1,int v1)
        {
            return 1;
        }
        public void iy(Func<int, int, int> f1, int v1)
        {
            int i = ix(f1, 1);
        }
        public void iz()
        {
            int i = ix(f, 1);
        }
    }

    class C
    {
        public static List<A> f(List<A> a, int v)
        {
            return new List<A>();
        }
        public int ax(Func<List<A>, List<A>, int> f1, int v1)
        {
            return 1;
        }
        public void ay(Func<List<A>, List<A>, int> f1, int c)
        {
            int i = ax(f1, c);
        }
        public void az()
        {
            int i = ax(f, 1);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: So what was the problem?  what have you tried and what was the error?

Answer (score 0):

You have a small error. Your method signatures are not matching.

You need to change your definition of C.F(..) it should be:

```
public static int f(List<A> a, List<A> b)
{
    return 1; //List<A>();
}
```

Comment: @DanielMann Are you implying that this is not an answer because he did not post a real question?

Comment: Thanks for leading me to the issue. My parameter order for Func was inverted; My Func(result,input) should have been Func(input,result).